# In on result, get a number of dependency

Tags: mysql

I have this MySQL DB :

[image]

MySQL in order to create DB + set of test value :

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS test;
CREATE DATABASE test;
CREATE TABLE table_status ( Id TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, Status CHAR(27) NOT NULL) ENGINE=INNODB;
INSERT INTO table_status (Id, Status) VALUES (1, 'CREATED'), (2, 'UNSURE'), (3, 'RUNNING'), (4, 'BEGIN_ACTION_TRUE'), (5, 'STOPPED_ACTION_TRUE_OK'), (6, 'STOPPED_ACTION_TRUE_NOT_OK'), (7, 'BEGIN_ACTION_FALSE'), (8, 'STOPPED_ACTION_FALSE_OK'), (9, 'STOPPED_ACTION_FALSE_NOT_OK'), (10, 'STOPPED_NOT_OK'), (11, 'STOPPED_OK'), (12, 'CANCEL_REQUESTED'), (13, 'CANCELLED');
CREATE TABLE table_group ( Id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, Status TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, CONSTRAINT fk_group_Status FOREIGN KEY (Status) REFERENCES table_status(Id)) ENGINE=INNODB;
CREATE TABLE table_task ( Id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, IdGroup BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, Status TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, Command TEXT NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT fk_task_IdGroup FOREIGN KEY (IdGroup) REFERENCES table_group(Id) ON DELETE CASCADE, CONSTRAINT fk_task_Status FOREIGN KEY (Status) REFERENCES table_status(Id)) ENGINE=INNODB;
CREATE TABLE table_dependency ( IdBeforeTask BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, IdAfterTask BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (IdBeforeTask, IdAfterTask), CONSTRAINT fk_dependency_IdBeforeTask FOREIGN KEY (IdBeforeTask) REFERENCES table_task(Id) ON DELETE CASCADE, CONSTRAINT fk_dependency_IdAfterTask FOREIGN KEY (IdAfterTask) REFERENCES table_task(Id) ON DELETE CASCADE) ENGINE=INNODB;
INSERT INTO table_group (Id) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4);
INSERT INTO table_task (IdGroup, Command) VALUES (1, "command_group_1_task_1"), (1, "command_group_1_task_2"), (1, "command_group_1_task_3"), (2, "command_group_2_task_1"), (2, "command_group_2_task_2"), (2, "command_group_2_task_3"), (3, "command_group_3_task_1"), (3, "command_group_3_task_2"), (3, "command_group_3_task_3"), (4, "command_group_4_task_1"), (4, "command_group_4_task_2"), (4, "command_group_4_task_3");
INSERT INTO table_dependency (IdBeforeTask, IdAfterTask) VALUES (1, 2), (2, 3), (4, 5), (5, 6), (7, 8), (8, 9), (10, 11), (11, 12);
```

The data in table_status is fixed to this :

```
INSERT INTO table_status (Id, Status) VALUES 
    (1, 'CREATED')
    (2, 'UNSURE')
    (3, 'RUNNING')
    (4, 'BEGIN_ACTION_TRUE')
    (5, 'STOPPED_ACTION_TRUE_OK')
    (6, 'STOPPED_ACTION_TRUE_NOT_OK')
    (7, 'BEGIN_ACTION_FALSE')
    (8, 'STOPPED_ACTION_FALSE_OK')
    (9, 'STOPPED_ACTION_FALSE_NOT_OK')
    (10, 'STOPPED_NOT_OK')
    (11, 'STOPPED_OK')
    (12, 'CANCEL_REQUESTED')
    (13, 'CANCELLED')
```

The purpose is to have a group containing task, each task can be dependant on another one.

What I want to obtain :

Group.Id, NB_TASK_TOTAL, NB_TASK_CREATED, NB_TASK_UNSURE

But there is a trap : The number of NB_TASK_CREATED is defined as : the number of task with status to CREATED and with no unresolved dependency.

An unresolved dependency is defined as a task depend on another wich have a Status != 11 (STOPPED_OK).

So if I have this :

```
table_dependency : 

IdBeforeTask    IdAfterTask
    1              2
    2              3

table_task :

Id  IdGroup     Status  Command
1     1           1     command_1
2     1           1     command_2
3     1           1     command_3
```

I want to have

```
Group.Id, NB_TASK_TOTAL, NB_TASK_CREATED, NB_TASK_UNSURE
 1          3                 1                0
```

Here my unsucesful try :

```
SELECT

G.Id,

(SELECT COUNT(T.Id) FROM table_task as T WHERE T.IdGroup = G.Id),
(SELECT COUNT(T.Status = 1) FROM table_task as T WHERE T.IdGroup = G.Id AND T.Id NOT IN (SELECT IdAfterTask from table_dependency as D1 join table_task as T1 on T1.Id=D1.IdBeforeTask WHERE T1.Status!=11)),

(SELECT COUNT(T.Status = 2) FROM table_task as T WHERE T.IdGroup = G.Id)

FROM

table_group as G
```

The problem is I obtain this :

```
Group.Id, NB_TASK_TOTAL, NB_TASK_CREATED, NB_TASK_UNSURE
 1          3                 1                3
 2          3                 0                3
```

(I have 4 group, each group containing 3 task, all the task with Status = 1 (CREATED) and the dependency set in order to have just on "resolved" dependency so i should have

```
Group.Id, NB_TASK_TOTAL, NB_TASK_CREATED, NB_TASK_UNSURE
 1          3                 1                0
 2          3                 1                0
```

instead.

I'm a beginner in MySQL, and i'm lost on this one request.

Comment: What do the tables `cpcm_task` & `cpcm_dependency` contain? Can you provide a sample of those as well?

Comment: ... sorry. cpcm_task == table_task and cpcm_dependency == table_dependency.
I fix that rigth away. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
SELECT T.IdGroup as Group_Id,
       COUNT(T.IdGroup) as NB_TASK_TOTAL,
       (SELECT COUNT(Tt.Id) FROM table_task Tt WHERE Tt.IdGroup = T.IdGroup AND Tt.Status = 1) as NB_TASK_CREATED,
       (SELECT COUNT(Tt.Id) FROM table_task Tt WHERE Tt.IdGroup = T.IdGroup AND Tt.Status = 2 AND Tt.Id NOT IN (SELECT IdAfterTask from table_dependency as D1 join table_task as T1 on T1.Id=D1.IdBeforeTask WHERE T1.Status!=11)) as NB_TASK_UNSURE
  FROM table_task T
 GROUP BY T.IdGroup;
```

Comment: I obtain 
1  3  3  0
2  3  3  0
3  3  3  0
4  3  3  0
Not
1  3  1  0
2  3  1  0
3  3  1  0
4  3  1  0
(How can I insert return carriage here ?).

Comment: I remplaced COUNT by SUM and I have the rigth result. Thanks ! My brain hurt me for the last hour with this problem.

Comment: @Tom's: Glad it was of help!